# cors request failing in sails.js while doing res.redirect()

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, cors, sails.js

cors request is failing

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://eampple.net/api/transactions?asset_id=76cb0099&payment_id=pay_6G28AnQUs6WkBK&plan_name=undefined.
>   The request was redirected to
>   'http://eampple.net/api/subscriptions/events?transaction_token=0364…8af7b4d98ee1f66d7ca0fbfd81b7e627781b6b81ba187e8e3d72ef49&asset_id=76cb0099',
>   which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

**in side cors.js

i have set

allRoutes:true

,origin:'*'**

for some request it working. but when i do redirect it is failing.

Comment: Where do you receive this error?. In your angular app?

Comment: in browser console i am getting this error.and i am using angularjs

Comment: Have you tried reading the error message? It says nothing about the value of the Access-Allow-Origin header not being `*`, so the routes stuff you mention doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: @user3398632 Can you try adding `cors: {origin: '*',headers: 'Content-Type, Authorization'}` in your sails route?

Comment: yes @DavidR i also tried that.not working.

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing redirecting in angular?

`$window.location.href = href;`

Was the only way I could get it to work with sails.

Comment: i call transaction endpoint .in side that enpoint i am using **res.redirect(url);** in sails. that does that redirection to subscription endpoint.